# Solving a particular kind of equation

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

Suppose that we have a rational function of the form 
$$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)},$$
where $P,Q$ are polynomials of equal degree with rational coefficients, for which there exists two complex numbers $x_1, x_2$ such that
$$\displaystyle x_1 = f(x_2)$$
and
$$\displaystyle x_2 = f(x_1).$$
Is there a relatively simple, non-messy way to do this? I would also accept clear, dummy-proof computer algebra solutions. The out put should be in terms of the coefficients of $P,Q$.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What do you want to do, really? What does that "this" stand for? If you want to find such $x_1,\,x_2$ given the $f(x)$, well, that's simple: look for the solutions of $f(f(x))=x$, which is equivalent to some polynomial equation. Any computer algebra system would gladly give you the numerical solution(s).

Comment: Yeah, what is "this"? What are you trying to solve for?